# How to tell Visual Studio 2010 to remember the position of the Find dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, replace, dialog

When I press Ctrl+F, the Find dialog appears in adventurous positions. When more than a whole screen full of text is selected, it appears completely off the bottom of the screen except for its title bar. Needless to say, this is not helpful.

A friend of mine, however, reports that the dialog is always in the same position for him and doesn't move about randomly like that. That seems to suggest that there's an option to control this behaviour. Any ideas where exactly that option can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can’t.

Comment: I think you can, check my added answer (or did I misunderstand the q?).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what's already written, here's an alternative: Just like other windows, you can fix the find window (glue it, pin it) to one position. This does the trick for me, it's always in the same location.

Comment: Fair enough — that is what I ended up doing to get rid of the problem. But of course it required getting accustomed to a completely new way of using the dialog. The question was *how to get rid of the described behaviour*, not *how to change my habits drastically so that I don’t have that problem anymore*, otherwise you could say “throw away your computer and go into bricklaying” is a valid answer.

Comment: @Timwi, I'm afraid I've no idea what you mean with the latter. The Find-window remains in place, functionality remains the same, and you can fully decide on what place it is. I don't see how that can be "drastically changing your habits" as nothing changes... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does Window -> Reset Window Layout help?

Comment: That sounds like it has all sorts of consequences on the positions of all other tool windows, so I don't want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

My find dialog was moving to odd locations every time I Ctrl+F'd to open it.  But then I accidentally closed it using the [X] in the top right corner instead of hitting ESC, and guess what, it saved the position, so try that.

As for "pinning" the window, I assume that means to "dock" it.  But that does not keep the same position on the screen (except by coincidence), only the same position within the developer environment, and if it's docked then every time you open it the other docked windows have to resize to make room, if you want all the find options displayed then you lose a lot of space in your docked windows area, plus you lose the ability to hit ESC to make it go away, plus after you close it you typically don't get the same arrangement back for the other docked windows.